# Django oscar sandbox editing or django oscar documentaion

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, sandbox, django-oscar

Is it okay to edit the existing django-oscar sandbox project as my project or is it better to follow the django-oscar documentation?

Comment: you mean contributing to the project as e.g github fork, or you mean creating your e-coomerce project based on the `django-oscar`?

Comment: If you are setting up your own project then it is better to follow the documentation. The sandbox can be helpful for debugging and/or checking your setup though.

Answer (score 1):

If its for your project, you should follow the docs. But you can always use it for references.

Answer (score 0):

> The sandbox site is a minimal implementation of Oscar where everything is left in its default state. It is useful for exploring Oscar’s functionality and developing new features.

As [stated in the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/sandbox.html#the-sandbox-site), you should only use the sandbox for inspiration or as a vanilla example. It may get quickly outdated with a new release, so it is always better to follow the main documentation.